# 1-query batch update array of users using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am currently looping through an array to update one row at a time, for example:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($users); $i++) {
    $query = "UPDATE users SET name = :name WHERE id = :id";
    $statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($query);
    $result = $statement->execute('name' => $users[$i]['name'], 'id' => $users[$i]['id']);
}
```

Is there any way to make this 1 query, or optimize in any way?

Comment: you can prepare the query only once - before the loop.

Comment: do you need to optimize it? how long does it take? does it affect the overall performance in any way? if so - how exactly?

Comment: If you  need to update a specific ID with a specific value then you need a specific update query so you can't avoid N queries for N updated rows. Preparing once may be a minor optimisation but the bulk of the time is looking for an ID and changing the name and you can't avoid doing that. If there was a general rule like e.g. update all ids between 10 - 100 and set their name to "bob" then that would be a different case

Comment: It takes a bit long when updating thousands of rows, there's a couple more columns being updated and a couple more in the where clause in my actual code. By preparing once, do you guys mean concatenating all my queries together? For example `"UPDATE users SET name = "name" WHERE id = 1";"UPDATE users SET name = "name2" WHERE id = 2";`

Comment: by preparing once you are just preparing your query once. What is "a bit long" in conventional measurement units like seconds, hours, years? Does it have to be performed online or by some background process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use foreach() and iterate $users array, bind values and execute statements inside the array

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE users SET name = :name WHERE id = :id');
foreach($users as $user)
{
    $stmt->bindValue(':name', $user['name']);
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $user['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```